# IfLanguageName versus iflanguage

Tags: babel, languages

The `babel` package recommends using the command `IfLanguageName` of the `iflang` package to test for a language.
It is explained that the command `iflanguage`  is too coarse, because it is only based on the hyphenation pattern.

But if for example, we would like to test if the current language is one of the four English, USEnglish, usenglish or american, do we have to do four tests for each one of these languages?

Is there any test for language families, for example one for the English language family that includes British, American and other variants?

Comment: `\IfLanguagePatterns{english}` returns true when the current language is `english`, `USenglish` and `american` (as specified in the option to `babel`). Also `\iflanguage{english}` does, but the test is less reliable in some circumstances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package `babel` knows more than four languages of the family English:

```
\DeclareOption{american}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{australian}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{british}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{canadian}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{newzealand}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{UKenglish}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
\DeclareOption{USenglish}{\bbl@load@language{english}}
```

And `babel` knows lots of hyphenation patterns (macro `\l@<language>`), from `english.ldf`

```
\ifx\l@english\@undefined
  \ifx\l@UKenglish\@undefined
    \ifx\l@british\@undefined
      \ifx\l@american\@undefined
        \ifx\l@USenglish\@undefined
          \ifx\l@canadian\@undefined
            \ifx\l@australian\@undefined
              \ifx\l@newzealand\@undefined
```

A detection of an English language would have to test either eight language names or eight hyphenation patterns.

### Non-expandable `\IfLangEnglish`

The following example defines `\IfLangEnglish` using LaTeX's `\in@` to check if an argument can be found in a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,british,canadian,australian,ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LanguageEnglishList}{%
  ,american,australian,british,canadian,english,newzealand,UKenglish,USenglish,%
}
\@onelevel@sanitize\LanguageEnglishList
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IfLangEnglish}{%
  \let\@LanguageName@\languagename
  \@onelevel@sanitize\@LanguageName@
  \edef\@next{%
    \noexpand\in@{,\@LanguageName@,}{\LanguageEnglishList}%
  }\@next
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \def\test#1/#2 {%
    \par \textbf{\IfLangEnglish{yes}{no}} (#1/\textbf{#2})\par
  }%
  \test start document/ngerman
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{%
    \test foreignlanguage/USenglish
  }
  \begin{otherlanguage}{british}
    \test otherlanguage/british
  \end{otherlanguage}
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{canadian}
    \test otherlanguage*/canadian
  \end{otherlanguage*}
  \selectlanguage{australian}
  \test selectlanguage/australian
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}
  \test selectlanguage/ngerman
\end{document}
```

The categories of the letters inside `\languagename` can be 11 (letter) or 12 (other) or even a mixup (e.g. first character has 12, the others 11). Therefore `\@onelevel@sanitize` normalizes the characters to category 12 for the comparison.

Result:

> [image: Result]

### Expandable `\IfLangEnglish`

The former `\IfLangEnglish` is not fully expandable because of assignments and definitions.

Therefore I would use the following definition for `\IfLangEnglish` based on the expandable `\IfLanguageName` of package `iflang`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,british,canadian,australian,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{iflang}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfLangEnglish}{%
  % The order can be optimized by putting more often used names first.
  \IfLanguageName{american}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{australian}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{british}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{canadian}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{english}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{newzealand}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{UKenglish}\@firstoftwo{%
  \IfLanguageName{USenglish}\@firstoftwo\@secondoftwo}}}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \def\test#1/#2 {%
    \par
    \csname if\IfLangEnglish{true}{false}\endcsname
      \textbf{yes}
    \else
      \textbf{no}
    \fi
    (#1/\textbf{#2})\par
  }%
  \test start document/ngerman
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{%
    \test foreignlanguage/USenglish
  }
  \begin{otherlanguage}{british}
    \test otherlanguage/british 
  \end{otherlanguage}
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{canadian}
    \test otherlanguage*/canadian 
  \end{otherlanguage*}
  \selectlanguage{australian}
  \test selectlanguage/australian
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}
  \test selectlanguage/ngerman
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `iflang` 2014/04/29 v1.7

The new version of `iflang` is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71873949/tex/iflang-1.7.pdf) until it hits CTAN.
(The `.dtx` file is embedded as PDF attachment, run it through plain TeX to get the unpacked package file.)

The new version provides test commands for language families:

```
\IfLanguageFamilyEnglish{<yes>}{<no>}
```

The implementation is based on the expandable `\IfLangEnglish` macro.

See the documentation for the supported language families and their included languages.

Comment: Thank you. As things stand, I should create an `iflangfamily` package that adapts your IfLangEnglish command to the other language families listed in section 1.1 of the `babel` manual.

Comment: Is it possible that for example `IfLanguageName{american}` returns false if only `usepackage[american]{babel}` is in the preamble? The `IfLangEnglish` command only works as expected over here if `babel` is loaded with the `english` or `british` option.

Comment: @user3528522: Please clarify the problem.

Comment: If you do one test at a time, by a minimal working example only containing `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}` and the `IfLangEnglish` command before `begin{document}`, then apparently `IfLangEnglish` does not return true.

Comment: @user3528522: I get `true` with both definitions if `\IfLangEnglish`. Check `\languagename` (`\show\languagename` or `\typeout{languagename: \languagename}`).

Comment: Thank you for the package update! I suggest `IfLanguageFamilyPortuguese` as the other families are by preference referred to by their English language names.

Comment: When there is more than one command in the if true-part of `IfLanguageFamilyGerman` then the second and following commands are also processed if `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. This appears to be a problem not considered by your test.

Comment: Regarding the prior problem: `IfLanguageFamilyEnglish` correctly returns true if `\usepackage[american]{babel}` but does not process the second and following commands in the if true-part of `\IfLanguageFamilyEnglish` if `\usepackage[english]{babel}`or `[british]`.

Comment: @user3528522: Thanks, a systematic copy and paste error that has affected most language families. It is fixed now.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The current version of iflang (2018/01/21 v1.7) has no support for language families any more?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Could we expect an iflang version with \IfLanguageFamilyEnglish on CTAN anytime soon?

Answer (score 5):

The [`translations`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations) package offers the (expandable)

```
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{<lang>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

test where `<lang>` is the name of what `translations` calls a base language. »English« is one of them. Other languages are *dialects* or *aliases* as far as `translations` is concerned.  `\ifcurrentbaselanguage{english}{<true>}{<false>}` puts the `<true>` branch in the input stream as long as the current `babel` language is either `english` or an alias (`English`) or a dialect (`british`, ...) or an alias of a dialect (`UKenglish`, ...)

All the tests in the following example print `yes` except for the first one where the current language is `ngerman`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,british,canadian,australian,newzealand,UKenglish,american,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{translations}

\begin{document}

% ngerman
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

\begin{otherlanguage}{british}
  \ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{canadian}
  \ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\selectlanguage{australian}
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

\selectlanguage{american}
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

\selectlanguage{newzealand}
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}

% this shows that the test is expandable:
\edef\foo{\ifcurrentbaselanguage{English}{yes}{no}}
\show\foo
% > \foo=macro:
% ->yes.
% l.32 \show\foo

\end{document}
```

[image]