# Language detection and condition

Tags: conditionals, babel, xstring

My problem is quite simple. I use the babel package and depending on the language I want to display something with respect to the active language. Therefore I use the package `xstring`. My code is the following

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french}

\languagename%show the string

\IfStrEq{\languagename}{french}{Yes, it's french!}{No, it's not french!}

\end{document}
```

This does not work. Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174165/iflanguagename-versus-iflanguage

Answer (score 4):

The minimal example with the [iflang](https://ctan.org/pkg/iflang) solution of [Javier Bezos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279939/language-detection-and-condition#comment674746_279943) would be:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{%
        \IfLanguageName{french}{Yes, it's french!}{No, it's not french!}%
        
        \selectlanguage{french}%
        \IfLanguageName{french}{Yes, it's french!}{No, it's not french!}%
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `\IfStrEq*`, because the string returned by `\languagename` consists of category code 12 characters.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\languagename%show the string

\IfStrEq*{\languagename}{french}{Yes, it's french!}{No, it's not french!}

\selectlanguage{french}

\languagename%show the string

\IfStrEq*{\languagename}{french}{Yes, it's french!}{No, it's not french!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that using

```
\iflanguage{english}{this is english}

\iflanguage{french}{this is french}
```

is far more simple without using the xstring package.

Comment: `\iflanguage` has three arguments. `\iflanguage {languagei}{true}{false}`. You should add  `{}` at the end if you don't want curious problems.

Comment: Use `iflang` (by Heiko Oberdiek) instead. As explained in the `babel` docs, `\iflanguage` is not reliable.

Comment: @JavierBezos I found no mentioning of the fact that `\iflanguage` is bad in the Babel manual. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @zrajm ‘... but note here “language” is used in the TeX sense, as a set of hyphenation patterns, and not as its babel name.’