# Translating a book: supporting both languages in a single project

Tags: conditionals

I am currently translating a project from english to spanish. The project is organized by using subfiles.

I want to move all .tex files to a 'en' folder, while creating a 'es' folder where I would copy the original english files and work from there.

The name of the files themselves will not change, however I would need to modify the parameter to the subfiles command like this:

```
\subfile{en/preface} - for English
\subfile{es/preface} - for Spanish
```

As I have tried, it works, however the ideal solution would be to store the language in some variable/command and use it to build the final filename:

```
{language_variable}/preface.tex
```

The naive solution would be to have two 'main' files, one for each language... but I want to have certain flexibility: if I am working on a given chapter and disable all other subfile commands, I would like to generate both english and spanish versions easily to compare page count, layout...

Is there any way to use conditionals or variables or both under LaTeX?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60112/multilingual-text-with-if-statement or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279939/language-detection-and-condition Maybe?

Comment: Those questions answer mine only in part (this would allow me to set the language of the document, for example)... Still i would need some way of altering the filename for \subfile command: by adding a folder name or adding to the filename, so that I can include one or other language.

I am not interested in keeping both languages in one file, since this would make comparison more diffcult.